# Magento 2.3 custom theme unable to remove

Tags: magento, magento-2.3

Hello i was trying to make custom theme in Magento 2.3 using this documentation [Link Here.](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html)
My directory look like this frontend>myvendor>mytheme inside is`theme.xml,registration.php and composer.json` nothing else.

Now when i remove this directory and check on Magento Admin Dashboard  the theme is still their it doesn't remove, so weird i check the database mg_theme nothing their only the default magento theme, i run `cache:flush & dump-autoload` still no effect, i was really confuse how come so hard to remove the theme ..

and i was really confuse becos at the beginning i did't run any of this command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:clear-static-content..
```

if anyone has broad idea how can i solve this please let me know.. i have read and check already the Magento documentation nothing is working..

Sorry for my bad english..

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove your theme from the database too. Please check if there is an entry in the `theme` table and if yes, please remove that record (I assume that your theme path is lowercase as you have put in your question):

`select from theme where theme_path ='myvendor/mytheme' AND area ='frontend';`

If you find an entry, please delete it:

`delete from theme where theme_path ='myvendor/mytheme' AND area ='frontend';`

Comment: i have done everything , i have check the database made query the path does not exist.. my table theme has only 3 data which is the default.. still looking for ways on how to deal with this ..